# Which one of these approaches is better or are they the same?

Tags: generics, methods, types, interface, unboxing

I want to know which of these two `FiniteStateMachine.AddState()` methods is better than the other, for example, does one require unboxing/boxing? or do both require unboxing/boxing? and if any of them is better than the other, which one?

```
public interface IState
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class FiniteStateMachine
{
    private Dictionary<string, IState> allStates = new Dictionary<string, IState>();

    public void AddState<TState>(TState newState) where TState : IState
    {
        allStates.Add(newState.Name, newState);
    }

    public void AddState(IState newState)
    {
        allStates.Add(newState.Name, newState);
    }
}

public class EnemySoldierSword_TakingHitState : IState
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public EnemySoldierSword_TakingHitState(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

    public class Program
{
    public var FSM = new FiniteStateMachine();
    FSM.AddState(new EnemySoldierSword_ChasingState("ChasingState"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `IState` is a reference type you cannot avoid boxing so the only difference is where the boxing occurs. If `TState` is a value type it will occur when calling `allStates.Add` otherwise it will happen when calling the `AddState` method.

Comment: I see, so there is a difference but that difference does not matters in this context, thanks a lot thats what i wanted to know, thanks